# How to extraxt and set path of android ndk .bin file in linux ubuntu?

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, android-ndk

Does anybody knows how to extract .bin file in Linux Ubuntu ? I will have to install android NDK. I downloaded it from Developer site and the file I downloaded as .bin file. I am using Eclipse IDE. I don’t know how to set the NDK path with this. When I go through Terminal and try to extract it using 7z it says no such directory found, maybe my directory given mistake. Can anybody knows how to extract and set NDK path into eclipse IDE ? Any help will be deeply appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the terminal:

```
chmod +x android-ndk-r10e-linux-x86_64.bin
./android-ndk-r10e-linux-x86_64.bin
```

The command will extract the android ndk into your working directory.

Then move it to the path you want:

```
mv android-ndk-r10e <PATH_DIR>
```

Set the path:

```
export NDK_HOME=<PATH_DIR>
export PATH=$NDK_HOME:$PATH
```

Comment: actually i can't find .bin file in downloaded package